# How to import the existing ECS Service into code_pipeline using cdk python

Tags: python, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

After I deployed ECS Cluster using EC2 instances.

Now I would like to write code_pipeline for deploying service to ECS Service cluster.

```
deploy_actions = aws_codepipeline_actions.EcsDeployAction(
                action_name="DeployAction",
                service=ecs.IBaseService(cluster=cluster_name,service=service_name),
                input=build_output,
            )
```

Cluster_name and ecs service_name have already existed.

I would like to import the existing cluster and service into code_pipeline using cdk python.

But it does not work.

Please guild me how to define `service=ecs.IBaseService`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method to import an existing ECS cluster  [from_cluster_attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/Cluster.html#aws_cdk.aws_ecs.Cluster.from_cluster_attributes).

CDK has multiple issues or defects so it may not work. For instance, from method to import an existing VPC did not work (not sure if it has been fixed).

Comment: yes, I am using `from_ec2_service_attributes` for importing ecs service

Answer (score 2):

As mentionned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63309956/4683950) we need the `from_cluster_attributes` function.

But you need to provide the vpc instance as well as the security group .

Here is the full code:

```
vpc = ec2.Vpc.from_lookup(self, "spin",vpc_id ='vpc-')
security_group = ec2.SecurityGroup.from_security_group_id(self, 'r-sg', 'sg-')
cluster = ecs.Cluster.from_cluster_attributes(self, cluster_name="-pi",
                                              security_groups[security_group], 
                                              id="i-0", vpc=vpc)
```